# Corresponding T-SQL to perform same encryption/decryption as C# code

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

Could anyone provide an example of performing exactly the same encryption/decryption as the C# code below, but with T-SQL?

The below functions are used to encrypt/decrypt given strings for later storage in a database. But I'm just curious to know whether there is a T-SQL-way of doing the exact same thing.

Note: The value of the string variable "EncryptionKey" is made up for this specific purpose

```
private string Encrypt(string clearText)
{
    string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
    byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return clearText;
}

private string Decrypt(string cipherText)
{
    string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
    byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return cipherText;
}
```

Comment: You can execute CLR methods from within SQL Server loading the assembly inside the DB. Did you consider it as a possible solution?

Comment: If I had to do encryption with specific algorithms in SQL Server, I'd probably be thinking about using CLR and so coding in C# anyway. Also, just as a side note, it's horrible to reuse a parameter to contain something completely different from its name. What `Encrypt` returns isn't `clearText` at all.

Comment: As Damien_The_Unbeliever, don't reuse "variables" like that. It doesn't save anything at all, and even if it did, that would be a silly micro-optimization. In fact, in this case, you don't need to store the string explicitly at all - just `return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());` directly :) 
Now, it's definitely possible to implement AES in T-SQL. The question is - why would you want to? Also, why not use database-level encryption? And an encrypted connection? Using a working implementation is a best bet. SQL servers often have a way to run plugins (eg. CLR on MS SQL).

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189586.aspx. There is a TRANSACT-SQL function to encrypt/decrypt, but is uses a different algorithm. If you want to use AES, you would have to do what the C# code does, which is delegate the actual encryption to an external library.